# File not found when running django collectstatic with django pipeline

Tags: python, django, subprocess, django-pipeline

This is my pipeline setting:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = SETTINGS_DIR + '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_files"),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineManifestStorage'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
    'beautycall.finders.LeftoverPipelineFinder',
)

PIPELINE = {
    'JAVASCRIPT': {
        'main': {
            'source_filenames': (
                'bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
                'js/script.js',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'compiled/main_script.js',
        },
        'datetimepicker': {
            'source_filenames': (
                'bower/datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'datetimepicker.js'
        },
        'typeahead': {
            'source_filenames': (
                'bower/typeahead.js/dist/bloodhound.js',
                'bower/typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.jquery.js',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'typeahead.js'
        },
        'remodal': {
            'source_filenames': (
                'bower/remodal/dist/remodal.min.js',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'remodal.js'
        }
    },
    'STYLESHEETS': {
        'main': {
            'source_filenames': (
                'css/style.scss',
                'css/fonts.css',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'compiled/main_stylesheet.css',
        },
        'datetimepicker': {
            'source_filenames': (
                'bower/datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'compiled/jquery.datetimepicker.css'
        },
        'remodal': {
            'source_filenames': (
                'bower/remodal/dist/remodal.css',
                'bower/remodal/dist/remodal-default-theme.css'
            ),
            'output_filename': 'remodal.css'
        },
        'website': {
            'source_filenames': (
                'css/website/style.scss',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'compiled/website/style.css',
        }
    }
}
```

Its return the error `raise CompilerError(e, command=argument_list, pipeline.exceptions.CompilerError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`. When using custom pipefinder, the pipeline seem to miss all the file in source_filenames. Im using Windows and its no problem when i try it in Linux OS, if its help.

It result in error when running this piece of code on django-pipeline :

```
compiling = subprocess.Popen(argument_list, cwd=cwd,stdout=stdout,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
```

At closer look the cwd argument seems fine, but 3 of 4 arguments in argument_list not exist when i checked it with `path.exist`. Idk if it supposed to be like that or no, neither i am know about `subprocess.Popen`

Any help much appreciated. Thanks